# How to set width for modal in flutter (modal_bottom_sheet package)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to have the modal have spacing on the sides as compared to it taking up the entire width but I'm having a hard time finding a solution with this package as it doesn't seem to have a `width` parameter that I can work with.

**Current result**:

[image: Current result]

**Desired result**:

[image: Desired result]

Notice how on the desired result, there is the spacing between the sides of the modal and the device edges.

**Here's the code I'm working with for the current result**:

```dart
Future<dynamic> preFocusModal(BuildContext context) {
  return showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Container(
      height: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I have tried adjusting the `width` of the child `Container` but that didn't work (figured it might because that's how it seems I can set `height`)

Also tried wrapping the modal in `Padding` but that would require another method extraction as the return type needs to be `Future` for the modal. This might work but I want to see if there's a more optimal solution.

Thank you!

**Solution**:

```dart
Future<dynamic> preFocusModal(BuildContext context) {
  return showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Container(
        height: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the container, add another container as child and add a margin.
And set `Colors.transparent` as the color of outer container.
Then adjust the properties of inner container to achieve desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the input, didn't think of that. Ended up with a slightly simplified version (didn't need all those containers) based on that logic. Posted the code above.

Comment: Great. Always look for simpler ways.